# graalvm installation/running in windows not working

Tags: windows, installation, graalvm

env variable and path is setting done but graalvm is not available.

```bash
java --version
java 22 2024-03-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22+36-2370)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22+36-2370, mixed mode, sharing)

gu install native-image
'gu' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

when using java --version - output is graalvm with version it will be displayed
gu list - it should be shown

Comment: this question does not really explain how did you install graalvm and have you seen sdkman ? you can install graalvm with it https://sdkman.io/jdks#graalce